# Deserializing JSON with serialized JSON in attribute value

Tags: java, json, deserialization, pojo, objectmapper

This is the JSON I received:

```
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "Id": "dc8872fa-dda3-5d97-808f-2b54ad904167",
  "Message": "[{\"CarNo\":\"123\",\"TransactionNo\":\"1234\",\"ReceiptNo\":\"12345\",\"Date\":\"05/09/21\",\"Time\":\"124204\"},{\"CarNo\":\"3425\",\"TransactionNo\":\"12912\",\"ReceiptNo\":\"1030010619\",\"Date\":\"05/09/21\",\"Time\":\"124204\"},{\"CarNo\":\"3425\",\"TransactionNo\":\"12912\",\"ReceiptNo\":\"1030010619\",\"Date\":\"05/09/21\",\"Time\":\"124204\"}]",
}
```

I want to map the message to the class `Event`:

```
public class Event {

    private String Type;
    private String MessageId;
    private List<Item> Message;
}

public class Item {

    private String CarNo;
    private String TransactionNo;
    private String ReceiptNo;
    private String LineNo;
    private String Date;
    private String Time;

}
```

Since the value of the message attribute is a String, I am facing difficulty to map it to the List.
How should I map the JSON received to the defined POJOs?

Comment: use JSONObject and ObjectMapper to read the value of json and deserialize it to your POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Jackson using a custom `JsonDeserializer`:

```
public class JsonStringListDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        if (value == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
    }
}
```

The deserializer can then be used for the Property `message` in `Event`:

```
@JsonProperty("Message")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonStringListDeserializer.class)
private List<Item> message;
```

Btw, you should use lower camel-case names for the members of a class (`message` instead of `Message`). You can still use upper-case properties in the JSON, by using the `@JsonProperty` annotation, as in the code above (`@JsonProperty("Message")`).

Comment: I actually created a class implementing converter interface - shrib.com/#Hailee23vg9dl. I am getting null values for all the attributes. Please let me know if I am missing something